# Oracle datafile: access contents accessing only file system

Tags: oracle, data-files

I'm trying to read and explore some data from a server I can't totally recover, I have full access to the filesystem (I have the harddisk, it's an easy scenario where the server has a single disk but I don't have the hardware to startup that machine back..I can just read file).
Now I'm wondering what's the best strategy to see table structures and data in a table space? (naturally I have all passwords!) Should I use any existing tool to read datafiles? Should I install a fresh oracle and import datafile somehow? any suggestion?

Comment: As far as I know the Oracle datafiles are in a binary format and can not be read directly.

Comment: What you are attempting requires an advanced DBA skillset. The best I can recommend is you read Oracle's "Database backup and recovery Guide" [[ http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/backup.112/e10642/toc.htm ]] and pick out the section that matches your situation and follow the steps.